# On mySql INSERT, how to throw an error only when existing duplicate differs

Tags: mysql

I have a table in my database with two columns, A and B.

> - A is the primary key, unique
> - B cannot be null

When I insert (newA, newB), I want to:

> - insert if newA doesn't exist
> - ignore if (newA, newB) already exists (no errors, no effect or overwrite same/existing pair)
> - return an error if a different couple exists with A = newA

This looks really simple, but I don't really see how to do that! I guess one way would be to set the primary key as (A,B), would that do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking back at my old pending questions, the answer here is quite simple:

- make (A,B) the key
- create an index on A to make it unique

This will enforce the desired rules.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

1. Create unique key (A, B). This will not allow the record with the same (A, B) combination to be inserted
2. Use INSERT IGNORE instead of INSERT so unique constrain you created on step 1 will not cause an error but will be silently ignored.
3. Manually check existence record with the same A value in before insert/update triggers and throw an error if such record already there. Something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `tbl_before_insert` BEFORE INSERT ON `tbl` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM `tbl` WHERE `tbl`.`A` = NEW.`A` AND `tbl`.`B` != NEW.`B`) THEN
        SET @msg = CONCAT('Record with A=', NEW.A, ' already exists');
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = @msg;
    END IF;
END
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Following this approach, are the triggers stored permanently in the database (not sure of where the 'live' in mySql)?

Comment: @Will59 Yes, triggers stored in DB. I do not know if you can use INSERT IGNORE instead of INSERT as you may not be able to modify the code. (feel free to accept the answer if the solution works in your case)

Answer (score 0):

You can keep A as the **Primary Key** while making the B field **UNIQUE**.

- Existing A Insert => It will throw an error (as it is the primary key).
- If new A, new B => It won't be a problem.
- If new A, old B => Because we made the B column unique, It'll throw an error.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not exactly what I'm looking for: the same B can be present in multiple (A,B) pairs, and if I insert an existing (A,B) pair ( the exact same pair), I don't want an error.